# SOAP API User best practice

Tags: soap-api

I'm running in a issue where the user password and token get reset every 30 days and I will need to update the code whenever password reset happens.

What is the best practice here ? Create an individual user solely for API usage ? or use one of the existing user's password ?

(I tried not to uncheck the force reset password option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice depends on your use case. If this is interactive, switching to OAuth may be a better fit. If this is for an integration, I would recommend a dedicated integration user for the following reasons:

1. If the user account is shared with a person, your sessions could conflict and cause each to be logged out.
2. If the API-only user is being used only from integration servers, the profile can be locked down additionally by IP and/or business hours, depending on the application
3. You can define a better password policy for the integration user
4. A shared account could be disabled if/when the user leaves the company, causing your app to be locked out